# onAuthStateChanged not navigating me to home screen

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-navigation-v6

I have been struggling with this for days now... When I try to login it does not automatically navigate me to home screen, unless I close and open app.
I am working with 3 separate components. However after I register once, this issue doesn't occur it only happens with new accounts.

```
const [userAuth, setUserAuth] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            user && auth.currentUser?.emailVerified ? setUserAuth(true) : setUserAuth(false)
        })
        return unsubscribe
    })

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Drawer.Navigator>
                    <Drawer.Screen
                        name='main'
                        component={userAuth ? MainDrawer : AuthStack}
                    />
                </Drawer.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </Provider>
```

This is my MainDrawer.js

```
export default function MainDrawer() {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <DrawerScreen {...props} />}>
            <Drawer.Screen
                name='drawer'
                component={HomeStack}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
            />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}

This is my HomeStack.js

    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='home'>
        <Stack.Screen name='home' component={TabNav}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='about' component={AboutUs}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='faq' component={FaqScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='userTerms' component={TermsScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name='privacy' component={PrivacyScreen} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is where you're trying to call `onAuthStateChanged`, it should be `auth().onAuthStateChanged(...)`. Also, I would change it a little bit

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUserResult => {
      firebaseUserResult && firebaseUserResult.emailVerified ? setUserAuth(true) : setUserAuth(false)
    })
    return unsubscribe
  })
```

Comment: I pulled```auth```  from my ```firebaseConfig.js```

```export const auth = firebase.auth()```

when I execute auth()... I get an error that its not a function

Comment: I understand. And if you console.log `auth.currentUser` does it come as expected?

Comment: My userId OR The user ID of the person logged in